# Flutter scrollbar on textfield

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, scrollbar, text-editor

I have full screen `TextField` that grow in size when the user added more lines/text. I want to add scrollbar for the user to know the size the TextField and where is he.

This is the code the my screen and TextField:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  TextEditor();
  @override
  _TextEditorState createState() => _TextEditorState();
}

class _TextEditorState extends State<TextEditor> {
  TextEditingController _editTextController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scaffold = Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => _backButton(),
        ),
        title: Text("File name"),
      ),
      body: _buildTextEditor(),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    );
    return scaffold;
  }

  Widget _buildTextEditor() {
    return TextField(
      autofocus: true,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: null,
      autocorrect: true,
      onChanged: (s) => {},
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        isDense: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  _backButton() {}
}
```

## This is what I have

[image: What I have]

## This is what I want, the scrollbar on the right

[image: What I want]

I could not find a way to do this and I don't an expert on Flutter to know how to do this on my own

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fortunately, the `TextField` widget accepts a scroll controller. This can be used to generate a scrollbar. See the example below.

```dart
TextEditingController _editTextController = TextEditingController();

// Initialise a scroll controller.
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

Then, add it to the `TextField` widget and wrap this widget in a `Scrollbar`!

```dart
return Scrollbar(
  controller: _scrollController,
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  child: TextField(
    scrollController: _scrollController,
    autofocus: true,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    maxLines: null,
    autocorrect: true,
    onChanged: (s) => {},
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: InputBorder.none,
      isDense: true,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
    context: context,
    removeTop: true,
    removeBottom: true,
    child: Scrollbar(
      thumbVisibility: true,
      child: TextField( //If you want initial value use TextFormField
        maxLines: 4,
        minLines: 1,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

After multiple tries, this helped in my case.

If you want to use with static read only text, user TextFormField with initialValue and readOnly true.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1)** Initialize a TextEditing Controller & ScrollController for the TextField and scrollbar.

```
TextEditingController _editTextController = TextEditingController();
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

**Step 2)** Create the TextField/ and the Scrollbar widgets.

```
Scrollbar(
  controller: _scrollController,
  child: TextField(
    scrollController: _scrollController,
    autofocus: true,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    maxLines: 3,
    onChanged: (s) => {},
  ),
);
```

This will create a TextField with the size of 3 lines. Once a user inputs more than 3 lines. The scrollbar will appear. Please note that I tested this code using a TextFieldForm not a TextField but I changed it to TextField to suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Give the text field a fixed height or a max height like below to add scroll bar

```
            Container(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLength: null,
                    maxLines: null,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```