# TextField with Scrollbar?

Tags: flutter, widget, textfield

i wan't to made a textfield with a scrollbar, but with a specific design, but i cannot moove this bar, if someone have the solution, i search a package or some solution but i don't have one, so i ask here maybe someone can help me.

There is a picture of what i try to reach.

[image: reach]

and this is what i have.

[image: ihave]

My code,

```dart
MediaQuery.removePadding(
  context: context,
  removeTop: true,
  child: Scrollbar(
    radius: const Radius.circular(5),
    interactive: true,
    isAlwaysShown: true,
    trackVisibility: true,
    controller: scrollController,
    child: TextField(
      scrollController: scrollController,
      scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

Thanks by advence.

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67475181/flutter-scrollbar-on-textfield

Comment: already tried but thanks :)

Comment: @MartinSaison did you get any solution for this? I have to implement the same in one project

Answer (score 0):

You could create own `ScrollableTexField` using `SingleChildScrollView` like this:

```
class ScrollableTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollableTextField({
    super.key,
    required this.placeholder,
    required this.controller,
  });

  final String placeholder;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  State<ScrollableTextField> createState() => _ScrollableTextFieldState();
}

class _ScrollableTextFieldState extends State<ScrollableTextField> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  double _thumbHeight = 0;
  double _thumbTop = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_updateThumbPosition);
  }

  void _updateThumbPosition() {
    double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    double viewportHeight = _scrollController.position.viewportDimension;
    setState(() {
      if (maxScroll != 0) {
        _thumbTop = (currentScroll / maxScroll) * (viewportHeight - _thumbHeight);
        _thumbHeight = viewportHeight * viewportHeight / (maxScroll + viewportHeight);
      } else {
        _thumbTop = 0;
        _thumbHeight = 0;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: TextField(
                controller: widget.controller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: widget.placeholder,
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  counterText: '',
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                    _updateThumbPosition(); // Update the scroll thumb position and height
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),

            // Track
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: _thumbHeight == 0
                  ? Container()
                  : Container(
                      width: 10,
                      height: constraints.maxHeight,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      )),
            ),

            // Thumb
            Positioned(
              top: _thumbTop,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: 10,
                height: _thumbHeight,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The widget has two parameters to provide `Placeholder` and `TextEditingController`.

In the code I use `TextField` with multiple lines of input and on change of the text I update the thumb position.
`PostFrameCallback` is used to ensure that thumb would be updates after for example select all and delete operation.
`Positioned` widgets are used to visual the Thumb and Track.

It can be used like this. I added some `Decoration` outside of the widget itself, but it can be embedded inside.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ScrollableTextField(
                  placeholder: 'Placeholder',
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]